# Why I cannot do final Widget[] children in Dart class

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class ExpandableColumn extends StatefulWidget {
  ExpandableColumn({Key key, this.title, @required this.children}) : super(key: key);
  final Widget[] children;
```

I cannot use this. It works for `final Widget children` but not for the array case. I suspect it's because arrays are not self constructible just like in C++? I tried doing `= new Widget[]()` but it won't work also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `final List<Widget> children;` 
For question in comments: It's `StatefulWidget`, you need to use `widget.children` not `this.children`
code snippet

```
class ExpandableColumn extends StatefulWidget {
  ExpandableColumn({Key key, this.title, @required this.children}) : super(key: key);
  final List<Widget> children;
  final String title;

...
return Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: widget.children);
```

Comment: but then I cannot use this children like this: `child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: this.children.`

Comment: return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: widget.children);

Comment: It's StatefulWidget, you need to use widget.children